# Using virtualenv with Tmux causes it to source additional packages

Tags: tmux, virtualenv

I previously was sourcing some setup files using my .bashrc file.

I've since removed this because I found that it was being concatenated with any virtual environment setup on my PC. I would check this using `pip list` within the environment

Now when start my normal bash terminal, virtual environment works as expected, however when I try to use my SAME virtual environment after starting tmux. `pip list` shows the same packages being concatenated to the list again.

What also was confusing was that both environments within and outside tmux has the same path from `which python3`.

I looked within my `.profile` and it looked normal.

Any help would be appreciated.

.profile:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```